# Why is it so difficult to prove that the discrete Fourier transform (DFT) cannot be calculated in faster time than $N \log N$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, computer-science, proof-writing, fourier-series, computational-complexity

As the title says, why is it so difficult to prove that the discrete Fourier transform (DFT) cannot be calculated in faster time than $O(N \log N)$?

This is a famous open problem in mathematics/theoretical computer science. Still, I cannot find any explanation why it is so difficult to construct a proof for it. Actually, I don't have any idea at all how proofs for such problems are usually written.

Comment: Don't know about you, but I'm still amazed that it can be calculated in less than $O(n^2)$..

Comment: You can calculate DFT in $O(N log N)$ using a fast Fourier transform (FFT) algorithm.

Comment: I know, *that*, it doesn't make it any less amazing :)

Comment: Generally lower bounds are much harder than upper bounds, mostly because upper bounds are usually constructive (you show algorithm with the desired performance) while for lower bounds you have to show that _no algorithm_ can do better. This is troublesome, because you don't have the algorithm at hand to use it for your proof, and when randomization comes in there is even more mess (if you want tight bounds, with loose bounds randomization simplifies things).

Comment: Moreover, you can actually calculate it in $O(K\log N)$ if the signal (sequence) is sparse in the frequency domain (see http://groups.csail.mit.edu/netmit/sFFT/hikp12.pdf). ($K$ is the number of nonzero frequency bins)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your comment nbubis :-) .. I'm not a native english speaker

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Intuitively, proofs that something *can't* be done are harder than proofs that something *can* be done, because the latter need only exhibit a way of doing it, while the former need to show that *any* possible approach will run into problems.  Most proofs of impossibility use additional structure in the problem to show that any approach needs some number of steps to 'clarify' the structure or to construct 'adversaries' who can make the problem more difficult.

For instance, the straightforward proof that sorting requires $\Omega(n\log n)$ operations is of this form; since there are $n!\approx n^{n+1/2}e^{-n}$ different permutations of the data and any binary comparison can only cut the search space in half at best, then we need a minimum of $\lg(n!)\approx n\lg n-kn$ comparisons to 'pick out' the sorted data, using a binary comparison model of computation.  This example also shows why specifying the model of computation matters; it's well known that sort on bounded data can be done in linear time(using e.g. bin sorts), and even that sorting on arbitrary sized integer data can be done more quickly than $\Omega(n\lg n)$ if the algorithm is allowed to perform arithmetic operations (and not just comparisons) on the data.  Contrast this against something like matrix multiplication, where even though the naive algorithm is $O(n^3)$ there are no specific constraints that 'force' algorithms to be slow, and in fact the time has been pushed down to roughly $O(n^{2.4})$ with no reason to believe that $O(n^2)$ (the naive lower bound) is impossible.

In short, then, the reason why it's so hard to show that the DFT requires superlinear time is that we have no specific reason not to believe that it *doesn't*; since we only have $O(n)$ pieces of data coming out of the operation, it's at least conceivable that some very clever algorithm can find them all in $O(1)$ time per piece of data, or $O(n)$ time overall.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear explanation!